# How to have permalink structure based on taxonomy terms

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks

I have a custom post type i.e `services`  & custom taxonomy `services_type`

I have custom permalink structure as /%category%/%postname%

`term1,term2,term3` are different terms under services_type taxonomy & `post1,post2,post3,post4` are posts

I i am trying to acheive is the permalinks as

```
http://example.com/term1/post1
http://example.com/term1/post2
http://example.com/term2/post3
http://example.com/term3/post4
```

but right now they are as http://example.com/services/post1

Following is what i have used so far

```
function wpt_services_posttype() {
  register_post_type( 'services',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Services' ),

      ),
      'public' => true,
      'supports' => array( 'title','editor','thumbnail','page-attributes','custom-fields'),
      'capability_type' => 'post',
      'rewrite' => array("slug" => "services/%services_type%"), // Permalinks format
      'menu_position' => 6,         
      'show_ui'=>true,
      'query_var'=>true

      )
  );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpt_services_posttype' );

//code for adding texonomy
function services_init() {
  // create a new taxonomy
  register_taxonomy(
    'services_type',
    'services',   
    array(
      'labels' => array(
              'name'=>'services type',
              'add_new_item'=>'Add New type ',
              'new_item_name'=>"New type" ,

              ),

      'show_ui' => true,
      'show_tagcloud' => false,
            'hierarchical' => true,
      'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'services' ),
         )
  );
}

add_action( 'init', 'services_init' );


add_filter('post_type_link', 'services_permalink_structure', 10, 4);
function services_permalink_structure($post_link, $post, $leavename, $sample)
{
    if ( false !== strpos( $post_link, '%services_type%' ) ) {
        $service_type_term = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'service_type' );
        $post_link = str_replace( '%services_type%', array_pop( $service_type_term )->slug, $post_link );
    }
    return $post_link;
}
```

I have tried  various codes  but it i am not getting any closer.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Yes, any of those are possible and configurable under Settings > Permalinks. Have a look at the Permalinks page for other possibilities.

```
/%category%/%postname%
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: ya i have custom  permalinks structure same  as  you told

Comment: try this /%category%/%post_id%

/%category%/%post_id%/%postname%

Comment: One thing to note though, it's suggested to add a number at the beginning of your permalinks to reduce the number of rewrite rules WordPress has to generate to resolve all of your URLs.

Comment: no that doesn't do anything,, anyways thanks for trying to help